# WinForm Timers Access Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, textbox, snmp

So I am trying to create a basic WinForm Application that uses SNMP, from snmpsharpnet.

I have two buttons 'Eye' and 'Jitter' that when one is pressed a timer starts which executes SNMP code inside the timer handler every minute.

I am trying to write the SNMP output to a textbox from the timer handler but everything I try either leads to thread exceptions or a continuous running process when I exit the program.

I have tried so many different things to fix those two errors that I may be screwing everything up but here is the code I have:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using SnmpSharpNet;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static bool stop = false; 
        static bool min = false, sec = false, eye = false, jitter = false;
        static string ipAdd = "";
        static System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        static int alarmCounter = 1;
        static bool exitFlag = false;
        static TextBox textbox;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textbox = outputBox;
        }

        private void IPtext_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ipAdd = IPtext.Text;
        }

        private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stop = true;
            timer.Stop();
        }

        // This is the method to run when the timer is raised.
        private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject,
                                            EventArgs myEventArgs)
        {
            timer.Stop();

            // If stop button has not been pressed then continue timer.
            if (stop == false)
            {
                textbox.Clear();
                // Restarts the timer and increments the counter.
                alarmCounter += 1;
                timer.Enabled = true;
                /*
                textbox.Invoke(
                    new MethodInvoker(
                        delegate { textbox.AppendText("fsjdaò"); }));
                */
                System.IO.StreamWriter file;
                if (eye == true)
                {
                    file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:/Users/bshellnut/Desktop/Eye.txt", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:/Users/bshellnut/Desktop/Jitter.txt", true);
                }

                // SNMP community name
                OctetString community = new OctetString("public");

                // Define agent parameters class
                AgentParameters param = new AgentParameters(community);
                // Set SNMP version to 2 (GET-BULK only works with SNMP ver 2 and 3)
                param.Version = SnmpVersion.Ver2;
                // Construct the agent address object
                // IpAddress class is easy to use here because
                //  it will try to resolve constructor parameter if it doesn't
                //  parse to an IP address
                IpAddress agent = new IpAddress(ipAdd);

                // Construct target
                UdpTarget target = new UdpTarget((IPAddress)agent, 161, 2000, 1);

                // Define Oid that is the root of the MIB
                //  tree you wish to retrieve
                Oid rootOid;
                if (eye == true)
                {
                    rootOid = new Oid("1.3.6.1.4.1.128.5.2.10.14"); // ifDescr
                }
                else
                {
                    rootOid = new Oid("1.3.6.1.4.1.128.5.2.10.15");
                }

                // This Oid represents last Oid returned by
                //  the SNMP agent
                Oid lastOid = (Oid)rootOid.Clone();

                // Pdu class used for all requests
                Pdu pdu = new Pdu(PduType.GetBulk);

                // In this example, set NonRepeaters value to 0
                pdu.NonRepeaters = 0;
                // MaxRepetitions tells the agent how many Oid/Value pairs to return
                // in the response.
                pdu.MaxRepetitions = 5;

                // Loop through results
                while (lastOid != null)
                {
                    // When Pdu class is first constructed, RequestId is set to 0
                    // and during encoding id will be set to the random value
                    // for subsequent requests, id will be set to a value that
                    // needs to be incremented to have unique request ids for each
                    // packet
                    if (pdu.RequestId != 0)
                    {
                        pdu.RequestId += 1;
                    }
                    // Clear Oids from the Pdu class.
                    pdu.VbList.Clear();
                    // Initialize request PDU with the last retrieved Oid
                    pdu.VbList.Add(lastOid);
                    // Make SNMP request
                    SnmpV2Packet result;
                    try
                    {
                        result = (SnmpV2Packet)target.Request(pdu, param);
                        //textbox.Text = "";
                    }
                    catch (SnmpSharpNet.SnmpException)
                    {
                        textbox.Invoke(
                            new MethodInvoker(
                                delegate { textbox.AppendText("Could not connect to the IP Provided."); }));
                        timer.Stop();
                        //outputBox.Text += "Could not connect to the IP Provided.";
                        break;
                    }
                    // You should catch exceptions in the Request if using in real application.

                    // If result is null then agent didn't reply or we couldn't parse the reply.
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        // ErrorStatus other then 0 is an error returned by 
                        // the Agent - see SnmpConstants for error definitions
                        if (result.Pdu.ErrorStatus != 0)
                        {
                            // agent reported an error with the request
                            /*Console.WriteLine("Error in SNMP reply. Error {0} index {1}",
                                result.Pdu.ErrorStatus,
                                result.Pdu.ErrorIndex);*/
                                textbox.Invoke(
                                    new MethodInvoker(
                                        delegate { textbox.AppendText("Error in SNMP reply. " + "Error " + result.Pdu.ErrorStatus + " index " + result.Pdu.ErrorIndex); }));
                            //outputBox.Text = "Error in SNMP reply. " + "Error " + result.Pdu.ErrorStatus + " index " + result.Pdu.ErrorIndex;
                            lastOid = null;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Walk through returned variable bindings
                            foreach (Vb v in result.Pdu.VbList)
                            {
                                // Check that retrieved Oid is "child" of the root OID
                                if (rootOid.IsRootOf(v.Oid))
                                {
                                    /*Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}): {2}",
                                        v.Oid.ToString(),
                                        SnmpConstants.GetTypeName(v.Value.Type),
                                        v.Value.ToString());*/

                        textbox.Invoke(
                                            new MethodInvoker(
                                                 delegate { textbox.AppendText(v.Oid.ToString() + " " + SnmpConstants.GetTypeName(v.Value.Type) +
                                            " " + v.Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine); }));

                                    //outputBox.Text += v.Oid.ToString() + " " + SnmpConstants.GetTypeName(v.Value.Type) +
                                       //" " + v.Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;

                    file.WriteLine(v.Oid.ToString() + " " + SnmpConstants.GetTypeName(v.Value.Type) +
                                   " " + v.Value.ToString(), true);
                                    if (v.Value.Type == SnmpConstants.SMI_ENDOFMIBVIEW)
                                        lastOid = null;
                                    else
                                        lastOid = v.Oid;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // we have reached the end of the requested
                                    // MIB tree. Set lastOid to null and exit loop
                                    lastOid = null;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("No response received from SNMP agent.");
                        textbox.Invoke(
                            new MethodInvoker(
                                delegate { textbox.AppendText("No response received from SNMP agent."); }));
                        //outputBox.Text = "No response received from SNMP agent.";
                    }
                }
                target.Close();
                file.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                // Stops the timer.
                exitFlag = true;
            }
        }

        private void eyeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            outputBox.Text = "Connecting...";
            eye = true;
            jitter = false;
            stop = false;

            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);

            // Sets the timer interval to 5 seconds.
            timer.Interval = 5000;
            timer.Start();

            // Runs the timer, and raises the event.
            while (exitFlag == false)
            {
                // Processes all the events in the queue.
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }

        private void jitterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            outputBox.Text = "Connecting...";
            eye = false;
            jitter = true;
            stop = false;

            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);

            // Sets the timer interval to 5 seconds.
            timer.Interval = 5000;
            timer.Start();

            // Runs the timer, and raises the event.
            while (exitFlag == false)
            {
                // Processes all the events in the queue.
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }

        private void Seconds_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            min = false;
            sec = true;
        }

        private void Minutes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            min = true;
            sec = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling DoEvents?

Comment: Where in the code are you getting "thread exceptions"?

Comment: When I was trying to access the textbox from the timer handler using the textboxname.Text, then I would get a thread exception. That is why I was trying to use Invoke. So basically I don't know why I still have a process running after I exit the app. Also I was using the timer format here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside your `TimerEventProcessor` function and check `textbox.InvokeRequired`.  That will tell you if your Timer is truly running on the same thread as your TextBox, and whether or not you need to use `textbox.Invoke()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are running into a deadlock on the UI thread.

`TimerEventProcessor()` is called by your instance of `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, which runs on the UI thread.  When the timer goes off, I believe it puts a message into the UI thread's message queue to call your `TimerEventProcessor()` method.  That method in turn calls `textbox.Invoke()`, which puts another message into the queue and then **waits for it to be processed**.

Your UI thread is now stuck, as it is in the middle of processing a message, but must wait until another message is processed before it can continue.  The calls to `Application.DoEvents()` do you no good, as they are not being called once your program enters `TimerEventProcessor()`.  (They're also unnecessary, since your button click handlers wouldn't be blocking the UI thread anyway.)

Since the timer runs on the UI thread, you can get rid of the `textbox.Invoke()` calls and just access `textbox` directly.

**Summary:**

1. Replace your calls to `textbox.Invoke()` with direct access to `textbox`
2. Remove your calls to `Application.DoEvents()`

**Note:** if you got the `Application.DoEvents()` logic from the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) for using a timer, they put it there so that the application doesn't quit once the Main function completes.

<s>**Update:** You can see if this is truly the issue by replacing your calls to `textbox.Invoke` with the following code.  If this code works, then you definitely have a UI message queue deadlocking issue.  Also, if this does resolve the issue, I would not recommend keeping this as the solution, but rather, addressing the deadlocking as suggested above.</s>

```
// Make the request asynchronously
System.IAsyncResult asyncResult = textbox.BeginInvoke(
    new MethodInvoker(
        delegate { /* insert delegate code here */ }));

// Process the message queue until this request has been completed
while(!asyncResult.IsCompleted) Application.DoEvents();

// Clean up our async request
textbox.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
```

Since you seem to have your code working, you can ignore the above test code.

Comment: Note: If the above understanding of the UI thread's message-processing behavior is incorrect, please let me know and I'll remove this answer.

Comment: Ok. So I can just access the textbox by it's name in the timer handler? Everytime I tried that, textboxName.Text, I would get the thread exception. That is why I was trying things such as textbox.Invoke(). And I want to be able to press a stop button and stop the timer from running so is that possible while the timer is going off? I thought that is why they had Application.DoEvents().

Comment: Are you trying to stop the timer from firing again, or are you trying to have `TimerEventProcessor` stop processing?  Either way, you don't need to handle `Application.DoEvents()` at the end of your button event handler.  As long as your program is running, the UI thread will continue to process its message queue.  The only time you would use `Application.DoEvents()` is if you need to pause a long-running method so that other messages in the queue can be processed.  If you're doing that though, you might as well move your long-running method to a background thread.

Comment: Ok. So I removed all the Invoke() calls and the Application.DoEvents(). I think I have it working now. It was just very confusing with the continuous process. This is the first program I've written in C# and I was trying to transpose a server-side JavaScript program I wrote to work this way. Just getting used to C#'s differences from Java/C/Objective-C etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One more question that I have is that what is the best way  to make sure your timer goes off immediately once you start it. I want to be able to gather information the first time and then wait a minute or whatever amount of time.

Comment: Since your timer runs on the UI thread, **and** you're calling timer.Start() on the UI thread, you could simply have your button click event handlers call your method first themselves, and then call `Timer.Start()`, as it would be roughly the same as having the timer kick off instantly and then again every interval after that.

Comment: If you want to use a timer to have your function fire once when the timer starts, and then again every x seconds, I would recommend using the `System.Threading.Timer` class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx). If you do that though, it would be running on a separate thread, so you would need to return to your usage of `textbox.Invoke()`, but it would have the added benefit of keeping your UI responsive, since all the work is done in a background thread in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to the timer and all the `Invoke` statements you use are not necessary. The `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` class operates in the UI thread. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

Comment: I realize it runs on the UI thread and that is why I was confused on where the process was coming from.

Comment: If the Invoke statement are "not necessary", then they wouldn't cause the thread exceptions and is therefore not helpful to the original question. -1